# Where to put Apex static files?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm installing Apex.

The installation went correctly but when browsing : http://localhost:8080/apex i'm getting the error :

**There is a problem with your environment because the Application Express files have not been loaded. Please verify that you have copied the images directory to your application server as instructed in the Installation Guide. In addition, please verify that your image prefix path is correct. Your current path is /i/ (it should contain both starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it.**

I don't know where I have to physically put the images folder.

Apex images are physically stored in the folder : C:\Apex\apex\images

When I run reset_image_prefix.sql and specify the same folder C:\Apex\apex\images, it's still not working and I get the error : **Your current path is C:/Apex/apex/images/ (it should contain both starting and ending forward slashes, such as the default /i/). Use the SQL script reset_image_prefix.sql if you need to change it.**

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks
cheers,

Comment: what instructions are you following?

Comment: Which instructions please ?

Comment: Are you using ORDS?

Comment: Yes I'm using ORDS

Comment: Check the standalone.properties file to make sure the static images settings are correct https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-standalone-mode

Comment: You can also try java -jar ords.war validate

Comment: Hi Thomas, did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

in standalone.properties file of ORDS configuration, there is a line that specifies the physical path of files :

**standalone.static.path=C:\blabla\images**